# How to return all the values with modification

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Here I want to return all the list with modifying the one object in the list. 
I have tried with the following code.

```
state = state.filter(item => {
  if (item.name === action.value)
    item.completed = true;
}); //I want to return all the state as same by modifying item.completed.
```

Comment: Do you want to `filter` the list for a subset, or `map` it to new contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are actually looking for is

```
// create new objects with their .completed property set to the condition
state = state.map(item => Object.assign({}, item, {completed: item.name === action.value}))
// or to keep previous true values (only "updating" those that match):
state = state.map(item => item.name === action.value
  ? Object.assign({}, item, {completed: true})
  : item)
```

or if you really want to *modify* the objects, then a simple

```
for (const item of state)
  if (item.name === action.value)
    item.completed = true;
```

would do it.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.. Will it return all the state with modification.

Comment: All the new state, yes.

Answer (score 1):

May use object assign:

```
state = state.map(
  obj => Object.assign({},obj, { completed: obj.completed ||  item.name === action.value})
);
```

Comment: But where is the condition ??

Answer (score 0):

```js
var action = {
  value: 'test'
}

var state = [
  {name: 'test'},
  {name: 'aaa'},
  {name: 'ccc', completed: true},
];

state = state.map(item => {
  if (item.completed || item.name === action.value) {
    item.completed = true;
  }
  return item;
});
console.log(state);
```

Comment: it is returning only `item.name === action.value` line satisfied object only, But I want to return with modification, All the state

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `return` statement in the `callback` function.

```
state = state.filter(item => {
        if (item.name === action.value)
           item.completed = true;
         return item.completed;
});
```